# Rails where LIKE pass dynamic attribute with there values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have search query and there I need to pass dynamic search attribute and values. Following query I am passing all field but those are not dynamic means Some time only first_name will be in search or some time first_name and last_name or some time first_name with age.

How the best way to pass those attributes and values as per found in search method.

```
Product.where(
  'first_name like ? OR last_name like ? OR age BETWEEN ? AND ?',
  params[:first_nm],
  params[:last_nm],
  params[:age_start],
  params[:age_end]
)
```

Comment: Wait, all the filters are in OR or AND between them?

Comment: Some are in OR and some are in AND

Comment: If possible use a gem. I recommend [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). If you want avoid gem take a params hash of attribute and value. Then loop through that hash and build your desired query string.

Comment: ok, thanks, I can try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for inputs, Following solution worked for me.
I think its pretty easy

```
params_hash = {}
if first_name
  where_str = 'first_name Ilike :ft_nm'
  params_hash[:ft_nm] = "swapnil"
end

if last_name
  where_str += 'last_name Ilike :lt_nm'
  params_hash[:lt_nm] = "patil"
end 

Product.where(where_str, params_hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic could help

```
level_one_result = Product.where('first_name like ? OR last_name like ?',"%#{params[:first_nm]}%", "%#{params[: last_nm]}%")
if (params[:age_end].to_i > 0 or params[:age_end].to_i > 0)
  if params[:age_start].to_i > 0 and params[:age_end].to_i > 0
     result = level_one_result.where('age >= ? AND age <= ?',params[:age_start].to_i,params[:age_end].to_i)
  elsif params[:age_end].to_i > 0
     result = level_one_result.where('age <= ?',params[:age_end].to_i)
  else
     result = level_one_result.where('age >= ?',params[:age_start].to_i)
  end
else
  result = level_one_result
end
```

Comment: it won't solve dynamic attribute passing to where like

Comment: You should treat it as the above, I think what I've already wrote could help

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would update your form to submit the params to reflect the columns to search on.  Then you can make this a bit easier with a scope:

```
ALLOWED_SEARCH_TERMS = %i(first_name last_name).freeze

scope :search, ->(terms) {
  result = all
  terms.slice(*ALLOWED_SEARCH_TERMS).each { |term, value| result = result.where(:"#{term}" => value) }
  result = result.where("age BETWEEN :age_start AND :age_end", terms.slice(:age_start, :age_end)) if terms.key?(:age_start) && terms.key?(:age_end)
  result
}
```

Then in your controller you can:

```
Product.search(params)
```